# how to input data with frequency using mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am having trouble on how to input data with frequency in Mathematica.
For example, I have 0 with 10,000 frequencies, 1 with 9000 freq, 2 with 3000 freq and 4 with 1000 freq.
Can anyone help me to input this data into mathematica and then I need to find the first, second and third moment of those numbers.
Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :

```
data = Join[ConstantArray[1, 9000], ConstantArray[2, 3000], ConstantArray[4, 1000]];

Mean[data]
Variance[data]
Kurtosis[data]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply :) however i dont know why when i include the "data = ..." it doesnt work. But then if i type Join[ConstantArray[1, 9000], ConstantArray[2, 3000], ConstantArray[4, 1000]] only, it works..

Comment: I'm surprised Mathematica doesn't have a built-in function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Table[
  fun[
    EmpiricalDistribution[
      {10000, 9000, 3000, 1000} -> {0, 1, 2, 4}
    ]
  ], 
  {fun, {Mean, Variance, Kurtosis}}
]
```

Comment: Upvote for including the value of 10000 for no good reason :)