# How to input an array with frequency?

Tags: python

Can someone help me how to input an array with frequency in Python? For example, I want to store five 1's, two 2's, one 3, and so on. We can simply let x=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,..]. However, when the frequency is large, this is going to be difficult. Is there an easy way to do this? What I am asking is same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247561/how-to-input-data-with-frequency-using-mathematica) but in Python.

Comment: You can use ``n*[k]`` to get a list of ``n``-times ``k``, e.g. ``5*[1]=[1,1,1,1,1]``. Do this for each number and concatenate the lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `*` and `+`. Take a look at [common sequence operations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

```
lst = 5*[1] + 3*[2] + [3]

print(lst)
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` you could do something like this:

```
np.concatenate([np.full(5, 1), np.full(2, 2), np.full(1, 3)])
```

The output of this code is:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
```

The `np.full` function creates an array with the same value repeated n times. For instance, `np.full(5, 1)` creates an array of 5 elements, all with the value of 1.

In case you need a list instead of a numpy array, you can convert it like this:

```
list(np.concatenate([np.full(5, 1), np.full(2, 2), np.full(1, 3)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `li` is a list, then:

```
li = []
li += ([1] * 5) #5 is the number of times you want to repeat 1.
print(li)
```

This gives an output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

You can keep adding other numbers to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform a list comprehension when the occurencies of the frequencies are stored in a dictionary:

```py
occurencies={1:5,
             2:7,
             4:5}
a=[i for key in occurencies for i in [key]*occurencies[key]]
print(a)
```